# Нужно удалить последний элемент массива без применения метода .pop()

Tags: javascript, массивы

Не могу справиться с задачей:
Необходимо написать функцию, которая эмулирует метод pop. То есть, нужно получать результат аналогичный pop, но без применения pop. Функция может быть вызвана много раз, при этом каждый раз должен удаляться последний элемент (я так понимаю arr7[arr7.length - 1]).
delete приводит к удалению только самого значения, но длина массива не меняется.

```
let arr7 = ['alex', 'nika', 'natali', 'jane', 'anne'];

function f7() {
  
  console.log(arr7);
}

f7();
```

Comment: Не понял задачу ты хочешь чтобы удалился последний элемент без метод pop() ?

Comment: Да, все верно, именно таккая задача стоит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

свойство [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) - особое. При его изменении меняется и сам массив.

Так, если присвоить значение, меньше текущего - лишние элементы удаляться.

Таким образом для эмуляции [`.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) нужно

1. получить последний элемент
2. уменьшить длину массива
3. вернуть полученный элемент

```js
let arr7 = ['alex', 'nika', 'natali', 'jane', 'anne'];

console.log(arr7);

function pop(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) return undefined;

  const el = arr[arr.length - 1];
  arr.length = arr.length - 1;

  return el;
}

console.log(pop(arr7));
console.log(arr7);
```

Comment: а что будет если увеличить длину, что будет лежать там?

Comment: @Danis, будет дырка. недостающие ключи не создадутся.

Comment: Это то, что нужно. Огромно спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё воспользоваться функцией [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
let arr7 = ['alex', 'nika', 'natali', 'jane', 'anne'];

function pop(arr) {
  const [deleted] = arr.splice(-1);
  return deleted;
}

console.log(pop(arr7));
console.log(arr7);
```

Comment: Да , все верно, но вся суть этих задачек в том, чтобы получать результат методов, не пользуясь ими. Такое условие...

Comment: Тогда стоило уточнить в вопросе, что нельзя использовать не только `pop()`, но и вообще все методы массивов)

Comment: Согласен, тупанул)

Answer (score 0):

```
 let d7 = ['china', 'india', 'brazil', 'japan', 'egypt'];

   function f7() {
      d7.length = d7.length - 1;
      console.log(d7);
      showArr('.out-7', d7);
  }

 document.querySelector('.b-7').onclick = f7;
```